# Hide ASP Website and SQL Ptored Procedures from Users

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, encryption

I'm creating a ASP.Net web application which will be hosted on different servers, and I do not want to show my code to others who have access to those servers. So, I heard of publishing pre compiled code in ASP.Net so that the code is secure.

But I also need to hide the stored procedures which are also main. So, How can I hide them ?? Like.. precompiling or converting into DLLs etc,

How can I do this??

Comment: you can create a stored procedure `WITH ENCRYPTION`..

Answer (score 1):

For the code you can `Publish` it and for stored procedure You can do by using `WITH ENCRYPTION` that encrypts the code behind your stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MyTest
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
SELECT *
FROM tablename
```

Check this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/01/sql-server-explanation-of-with-encryption-clause-for-stored-procedure-and-user-defined-functions/)

You may also check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)